# Is there any code that I can use in R to install all missing packages in any code automatically?

Tags: r

I'm tired of install missing packages. So is there any code or way that finds missing packages in the code and installs them all automatically?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Repeat after me:  Create. A. Package.  Because you cannot install a package without its dependencies.  Feel free to reinvent the wheel of dependency mechanism, again, but I believe our's rolls rather smoothly after 25 years of development, testing and improvements to it. (And no I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `attachment` package and especially function `create_dependencies_file()`